# How to make awk print one of 2 different fields based on which of it matches the condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I have a ascii table in Linux which would look like this:

```
Oct  Dec  Hex  Char                   Oct  Dec  Hex  Char
-------------------------------------------------------------

056  46   2E   .                      156  110  6E   n
```

I want to build a one liner in awk, which would match the 3rd and 7th field to corresponding hex character , say "2E". If 3rd field matches then print 4th field, i.e ".". Else if 7th field matches to "2E", then print corresponding 8th field.

I have written something like this:

```
man ascii | awk '$3 == "2E"{print $4};$7 == "2E"{print $8}'
```

Output:

```
  .
```

But the above works only if the match happens in 3rd field. If it happens in 7th field it prints nothing. For example for this case:

```
man ascii | awk '$3 == "6E"{print $4};$7 == "6E"{print $8}'
```

Expected output:

```
  n
```

Output I'm getting:

```
   nothing
```

Comment: Your code [seems to work well](https://ideone.com/QCw44T).

Comment: Check if you have DOS line breaks in your input by doing `cat -A file`

Comment: It is possible that the reason of the failure is the pager of `man`. Have a look at `man man` to check the default pager used. What you should do, is process the whole thing with `cat` as a pager:  `man -P cat ascii | awk ...`

Comment: Works for me as expected. However, if all you want to do is to convert hex to ascii you might as well use `printf '\x6E'`, or rather `hex=6E; printf "\\x$hex"`.

Comment: @Socowi That works great. I would rather use it instead of the complex awk

Comment: What do you see with `man ascii | grep 6E` ?